# Unset windows environment variable in puppet exec

Tags: windows, puppet

I am getting an error when trying to unset the JAVA_HOME environment variable in the puppet exec type.

```
exec { "$base_dir/bin/service.bat install": environment => ['JRE_HOME=C:\\jdk1.8.0\\jre', 'JAVA_HOME='], }
```

This is puppet version 3.4.3 on windows server 2012.  The error I get is:

```
Warning: Exec[E:/tomcat/bin/service.bat install](provider=windows): Cannot understand environment setting "JAVA_HOME="
```

Please let me know if you have ideas on getting this to work or working around the issue.

Comment: Converted from an incomplete answer: Have you tried `JAVA_HOME=""`? - That had not worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up working around the issue with an extra exec to call set:

```
node default {
  exec { 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c set JAVA_HOME=': 
    logoutput => true,
  } ->

  exec { 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c echo %JAVA_HOME%': 
    logoutput => true,
  }
}
```

Comment: Seeing as the `set JAVA_HOME=` syntax is supposed to work, the `exec` type's inability to accept such an environment setting should be considered a bug. Could you report this to Puppet? https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/ (Side note, I find the fact that this works accross multiple invocations of `cmd.exe` rather disturbing.)